# Adding SVN hooks - downtime required?

Tags: svn, hook

I have been asked to add a hook script to some SVN repositories. The repositories run under Apache with the `mod_dav_svn` module.

Do I need to restart Apache in order that the hook is picked up or will it Just Work from the moment the file is there and executable?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to restart Apache

No. SVN-hooks aren't Apache side of game, it's pure Subversion toys, thus - create and use immediately on svn-events

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should happen immediately. No apache restart required.